# Adding another image using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Please find the code and advise.

I am trying to add an another image ('correct10.png') onClick Event of displayed image i.e 'Van.png'. But nothing happend, so please suggest.

Here the html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Adding Another Image onClick</title>
<script>
function doImgSwap()
{
document.getElementById('newImg').addEventListener('click', function(e){
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.setAttribute('src','correct10.png');
e.target.appendChild(img);
});
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p><a href="#" id="newImg" onClick="doImgSwap()"><img src="van.png"></a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `doImgSwap` method creates an event handler, it does not actually swap the image.

Should be:

```
function doImgSwap(el){
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.setAttribute('src','correct10.png');
    el.appendChild(img);
}
```

And you'll have to pass in the element in the `onClick` attribute, like this

`onClick="doImgSwap(this)"`

here's a [working jsfiddle of your code](http://jsfiddle.net/x47ub9LL/)

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <title>Adding Another Image onClick</title>
        <script>
            window.onload = function() {
                document.getElementById('newImg').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
                    var img = document.createElement('img');
                    img.setAttribute('src', 'correct10.png');
                    this.appendChild(img);
                });
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <p>
            <a href="#" id="newImg">
                <img src="van.png"/>
            </a>
        </p>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: thanks dear, also pl. suggest if I have 3 options and you have to choose any one, as the same we choose while using Radio Buttons, in that case how can we find the element and want to place same functionalily on the clicked element.

Answer (score 0):

start by putting the js file under your html or use window.onload function to be sure

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Adding Another Image onClick</title>
  </head>
  <body>
     <p><a href="#" id="newImg" onClick="doImgSwap()"><img src="van.png"></a></p>
   <script>
 function doImgSwap()
{
document.getElementById('newImg').addEventListener('click', function(e){
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.setAttribute('src','correct10.png');
e.target.appendChild(img);
});
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: sorry dear, putting same code in html, not nothing happened.